# How to check if a property is dirty

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The `isDirty`-flag on a model indicates that one or more properties are changed and not saved to the server, but is it possible to check this for a specific property?

Like this: `model.isPropertyDirty('name')`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No, but it is possible to detect it with `propertyDidChange` method.

See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_propertyDidChange

You could store changed properties and implement your own `isPropertyDirty`.

Comment: Link broken, I don't find information for this method :/

Comment: You are right @medokin, I just figured out you have to have active the _Show Private_ checkbox or if not the anchor is not working.

Answer (score 17):

Actually Ember does provide a way to look up which attributes are dirty.

`model.changedAttributes()`

- https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Model/methods/changedAttributes?anchor=changedAttributes
- http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/working-with-records/

This method even gives you the before and after of changes per-attribute on your model! So cool!

To your question, you can check if the model's attribute `model.name` is dirty like so...

`Ember.isPresent( model.changedAttributes().name )`

Comment: hasDirtyAttributes as well. This does however not work for belongsTo relationships.